# Remake for-loop to numpy broadcast

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, steganography

I'm trying to code LSB steganography method via numpy arrays. I got code which makes the bool index mask, which will give those bits of red channel, which need to xor with 1.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

message = 'Hello, World!'
message_bits = np.array(map(bool, map(int, (''.join(map('{:b}'.format, bytearray(message)))))), dtype=np.bool)
img = imread('screenshot.png')
xor_mask = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.bool)
ind = 0 
for j, line in enumerate(xor_mask):
    for i, column in enumerate(line):
        if ind < len(message_bits):
            xor_mask[j, i, 0] = message_bits[ind]
            ind += 1            
        else:
            break
    else:
        continue
    break         
img[xor_mask] ^= 1
```

Is there more compact way to construct the xor_mask? Maybe through numpy broadcast

UPD:
Reduced my for-loop to this:

```
for j, line in enumerate(xor_mask):
    if ind < len(message_bits):
        xor_mask[j, :, 0] = message_bits[ind]
        ind += len(xor_mask[j])
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pad `message_bits` to have as many elements as pixels in `xor_mask` then it gets simple:

```
xor_mask = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.bool)
xor_mask[:, :, 0] = np.reshape(message_bits, xor_mask.shape[:2])
```

Another way, without padding:

```
xor_mask[:, :, 0].flat[:len(message_bits)] = message_bits
```

Comment: I added a way to do this without padding is using `flat`. However, in this case you won't have a choice of row- vs. column-major order as `np.reshape` gives you.